# COUNT DISTINCT with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I have two mySQL queries concerning the number of users:

First would be like:

```
SELECT
date_format(r.dataZalozenia,'%Y-%m') as rok_miesiac,
count(distinct r.idUsera) as liczba_buyers

FROM
rezerwacje r

WHERE
r.dataZalozenia >= '2017-01-01'
and r.status = 'zabookowana'

GROUP BY
1
```

And results in:

```
"rok_miesiac"   "liczba_buyers"
"2017-01"   "12862"
"2017-02"   "10208"
"2017-03"   "10189"
"2017-04"   "10993"
"2017-05"   "10705"
```

The second would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
r.idUsera,
count(r.idUsera) as l_reze

FROM
rezerwacje r

WHERE
r.dataZalozenia between '2017-04-01' and '2017-04-30'
and r.status = 'zabookowana'

GROUP BY
r.idUsera

ORDER BY
l_reze DESC
```

And results in:

```
idUsera l_reze
516287  8
2495710 6
2195860 6
645233  5
98308   5
543007  5
1464142 5
3461665 5
3443141 5
3818844 4
2305130 4
```

etc. i.e. basically user_id and number of reservations. I get 10768 rows in this case i.e. 10768 distinct user_id (this is for April only).

How come for April 1st query returns 10993 distinct user_id (I think) while 2nd query returns 10768?

Comment: Perhaps the distinct user count isn't growing that much?  The results are perfectly reasonable if we assume only a 225 users added outside of April.  This implies alot of revisits/reuse.  you could use both queries select from first where not exists in second and if you get 225 I think you have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dataZalozenia` is a datetime or timestamp, your BETWEEN will not include the majority of records from the end date; '2017-04-30' is treated as '2017-04-30 00:00:00'.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to hit the spot.. I totally forgot that this is treated like that. Thank you!

Comment: @radek Also note that `SELECT DISTINCT ... COUNT` is not the same as `SELECT ... COUNT(DISTINCT`

Comment: That I know. I feel the difference and I should be able to use it correctly. I do not have much practice yet tough. Thanks again.